# How do I Put in a pass through Table name so the Macro isn't bounded to the one worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, excel-tables, listobject

I'm trying to put together a Worksheet where if I click on a button on top it passes my conditional formatting through, as well as inserting a new line. However I feed through the Table name in the code, so if I try to copy the worksheet or try running the macro on another sheet, it breaks.

I put the code in ** around the changes i'm thinking of, however I'm stuck how to pass it on the **Set** line.

Help please!!

Example:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
**Dim tbl As ListObject**

Set ws = ActiveSheet
**Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)** <-- This lets me get the table name if this worksheet is copied.


Dim rng As Range
  
Set rng = ws.[TableName[ColumnName]]
**Set rng = ws.[tbl[ColumnName]]** <- If I do this it Breaks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can actually use structured referencing in VBA. At least, my efforts at trying to have consistently failed. Therefore I use code as shown below.

```
Private Sub Test1()

    Dim Ws      As Worksheet
    Dim Rng     As Range
    Dim Tbl     As ListObject
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Tbl = Ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set Rng = Tbl.ListColumns("Pair").Range
    Debug.Print Rng.Address
End Sub


Private Sub Test2()

    Dim Ws      As Worksheet
    Dim Rng     As Range
    Dim Tbl     As ListObject
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Tbl = Ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set Rng = Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2)
    Debug.Print Rng.Address
End Sub
```

In the first example you can use the columns name - replace the actual name with a variable of string data type if you prefer - but you get the ListColumn's range. The second example uses an index number to identify the column but you get the column of the DataBodyRange which doesn't include the header and total rows.

Comment: Example one was working exactly as I needed it. This is great. TY!
I had to have variable start at 2 instead of 1 for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

### Modify Table

- Copy the code into a **standard** module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Adjust the two `const`ants to fit your needs.
- Best used with a button on each sheet with the **same first table**.

**What does it do?**

- In column "`Name`" of the first table in a worksheet, it colors the
  fonts to red (`3`).
- Then it adds a new row to the table and writes a number to each cell.
- Additionally it shows some property values of the `ListColumn` and `ListRow`
  objects in the Immediate window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> of the Visual Basic Editor <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (VBE).

**Features**

- With a limited set of options for the `ListRow` and `ListColumn`
  objects, you want to 'transfer' them to a 'normal' range object and
  then apply some changes.
- For `ListColumns` **DataBodyRange** is used unlike **Range** for
  `ListRows`.
- `j` instead of the usual `i` is used to highlight that we are looping through **columns** of the row.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub modifyTable()

    Const TableNameOrIndex As Variant = 1
    Const ColumnID As Variant = "Name" ' or use e.g. 3 for the third column.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    
    ' Columns
    Debug.Print String(20, "'")
    Dim lCol As ListColumn: Set lCol = tbl.ListColumns(ColumnID)
    With lCol
        Debug.Print .Name                    ' Header Title
        Debug.Print .DataBodyRange.Address   ' Range Address
        Debug.Print .Index                   ' Index
        Debug.Print .Parent.Name             ' TableName
    End With

    ' !!! The following block will modify your table !!!
    Debug.Print String(20, "'")
    Dim rngCol As Range: Set rngCol = lCol.DataBodyRange
    With rngCol
        ' e.g.
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
    
    ' Rows
    Debug.Print String(20, "'")
    Dim lRow As ListRow: Set lRow = tbl.ListRows(3)
    With lRow
        Debug.Print .Range.Address           ' Range Address
        Debug.Print .Index                   ' Index
        Debug.Print .Parent.Name             ' TableName
    End With
    
    ' !!! The following block will modify your table !!!
    ' To add a new row:
    Set lRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    Dim rngRow As Range: Set rngRow = lRow.Range
    With rngRow
        ' e.g.
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Cells(j).Value = j
        Next j
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: TY for your response. I did not think about moving the code into a General module, was able to utilize your answer and Variatus' answer to make mine work!